# Trouble Parsing XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

I am having some trouble parsing some XML from centovacast v3 XML API. I've worked with their 2.x API and parsed it, but the responses have totally changed and I cannot seem to make any of my existing parsers work. Every example I've tried I cannot seem to get at the data correctly.

I'm using .NET 3.5 (4.0 is acceptable as well), any examples would be greatly appreciated.

An example XML document is:

```
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<centovacast version=""3.0.0"" host=""0.0.0.0:2199"">
    <response type=""success"">
        <message>OK</message>
        <data>
            <row>
                <id>1</id>
                <parameters>
                    <ipaddress>127.0.0.1</ipaddress>
                    <port>2198</port>
                    <title>Local server</title>
                    <isrelay>1</isrelay>
                    <ismaster>1</ismaster>
                    <defaultip>0.0.0.0</defaultip>
                    <daemontype>RPC</daemontype>
                    <hostname/>
                </parameters>
                <status>
                    <memfree>101879808</memfree>
                    <memtotal>1073741824</memtotal>
                    <memavail>778653696</memavail>
                    <swapfree>1077501952</swapfree>
                    <swaptotal>1077501952</swaptotal>
                    <buffers>172535808</buffers>
                    <cpuload>0.00</cpuload>
                    <uptime>13372713</uptime>
                    <machine>Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5620</machine>
                    <osbrief>Linux</osbrief>
                    <osdetails>2.6.18</osdetails>
                    <other>
                        <Processes>
                            <field>n</field>
                            <field>72</field>
                        </Processes>
                        <Kernel>
                            <field>s</field>
                            <field>Linux version 2.6.18</field>
                        </Kernel>
                        <row>
                            <field>f</field>
                            <field>0.000000</field>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <field>f</field>
                            <field>0.000000</field>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <field>f</field>
                            <field>0.000000</field>
                        </row>
                    </other>
                    <online>1</online>
                </status>
                <accounts>
                    <licensed>-1</licensed>
                    <active>1</active>
                    <inactive>0</inactive>
                </accounts>
            </row>
        </data>
    </response>
</centovacast>
```

I've tried using the following code:

```
        var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmldata);
        var query = from p in xml.Descendants("status")
                    select p;
        foreach (var record in query)
            MessageBox.Show(record.Value);
```

but it returns all the data inside the `<status>` and `<parameters>` in one big jumble, rather then in separate values.

I would love to serialize / deserialize, as the XML call I'm making returns the above for each server in the cluster, so it could be quite a large result set, but I am not picky, I would be happy just being able to get the data into the correct variables so I can use them.

Comment: What do you need from the XML? And in what format?

Comment: i would like to collect the data inside the Parameters, and Status, as well as the ID.. and i would like to keep them in the native formats, for instance isrelay would be a bool, port is int, etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example storing some of the elements in an anonymous type:

```
var data =
    XDocument.Parse(xml)
    .Root
    .Element("response")
    .Element("data")
    .Elements("row")
    .Select(row =>
        new
        {
            Id = Int32.Parse(row.Element("id").Value),
            Parameters = new
            {
                IpAddress = row.Element("parameters").Element("ipaddress").Value,
                port = Int32.Parse(row.Element("parameters").Element("port").Value),
            },
            Status = new
            {
                MemFree = Int32.Parse(row.Element("status").Element("memfree").Value),
            },
        });
```

You can always plug in your own concrete types and null checks where option values might be.

Answer (score 0):

`xml.Descendants("status")` returns the whole element `status` together with it's child elements. If you want to enumerate it's elements use the following code:

```
xml.Descendants("status").Descendants();
```

Comment: this seems to work perfectly, however i'm still left with if i parse the <parameters> in a foreach loop first, then parse the <status>, the data does not match the correct servers, so i would need to parse both <parameters> and <status> all at the same time or find a way to order it all by the <id>

Comment: could i use the above example to throw all the names and values into a dictionary and then pull out the data as i need/want it? say using dict["ipaddress"] or something like that?